# installing GSL on Windows XP 32bit for use with codeblocks

Tags: c++, windows, installation, gsl

I am trying to install Gnu Scientific Library (GSL) on Windows XP, but this is very difficult for me. I found this site

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsl.htm

from which I downloaded "Complete package, except sources" and installed. But this is only 6.2MB large, which I find to be very small. Is this correct? I would be happy to get some help with this.

I don't understand why this has to be so difficult.

Answer (score 4):

I am beginner as well, but I just managed to have it work on windows 8 with codeblock 12.11.

- installing gsl from the file you mention. Better to use a filepath without spaces (not sure if relevant here, just read this advices for installing other libraries)
- in codeblocks, after creating your project:
- right click on project name
- click on build options
- on the right part of the windows that opens, select the name of the project (root of the tree)
- select the linker settings tab
- click add
- browse to the lib directory of your gsl installation and select libgsl.a
- same for libgslcblas.a
- select the search directories tab
- click add and select the include directory of your gsl installation.

From this point things worked ok for me.

good luck.