# Error in the basic GSL example program - simple nonlinear fitting

Tags: c, gsl, nonlinear-optimization

I just got GSL set up on my windows box and I am trying to learn how to use the nonlinear fitting functions. First thing I did was pull an example directly off their website: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Example-programs-for-Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Fitting.html

which is here:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_multifit_nlin.h>
#define N 40
#define FIT(i) gsl_vector_get(s->x, i)
#define ERR(i) sqrt(gsl_matrix_get(covar,i,i))

struct data {
    size_t n;
    double * y;
    double * sigma;
};

int expb_f (const gsl_vector * x, void *data, gsl_vector * f)
{
    size_t n = ((struct data *)data)->n;
    double *y = ((struct data *)data)->y;
    double *sigma = ((struct data *) data)->sigma;

    double A = gsl_vector_get (x, 0);
    double lambda = gsl_vector_get (x, 1);
    double b = gsl_vector_get (x, 2);

    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        /* Model Yi = A * exp(-lambda * i) + b */
        double t = i;
        double Yi = A * exp (-lambda * t) + b;
        gsl_vector_set (f, i, (Yi - y[i])/sigma[i]);
    }

    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

int expb_df (const gsl_vector * x, void *data, gsl_matrix * J)
{
    size_t n = ((struct data *)data)->n;
    double *sigma = ((struct data *) data)->sigma;

    double A = gsl_vector_get (x, 0);
    double lambda = gsl_vector_get (x, 1);

    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        /* Jacobian matrix J(i,j) = dfi / dxj, */
        /* where fi = (Yi - yi)/sigma[i],      */
        /*       Yi = A * exp(-lambda * i) + b  */
        /* and the xj are the parameters (A,lambda,b) */
        double t = i;
        double s = sigma[i];
        double e = exp(-lambda * t);
        gsl_matrix_set (J, i, 0, e/s);
        gsl_matrix_set (J, i, 1, -t * A * e/s);
        gsl_matrix_set (J, i, 2, 1/s);
    }
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

int expb_fdf (const gsl_vector * x, void *data, gsl_vector * f, gsl_matrix * J)
{
    expb_f (x, data, f);
    expb_df (x, data, J);

    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}


void print_state (size_t iter, gsl_multifit_fdfsolver * s);

int main (void)
{
    const gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_type *T;
    gsl_multifit_fdfsolver *s;
    int status;
    unsigned int i, iter = 0;
    const size_t n = N;
    const size_t p = 3;

    gsl_matrix *covar = gsl_matrix_alloc (p, p);
    double y[N], sigma[N];
    struct data d = { n, y, sigma};
    gsl_multifit_function_fdf f;
    double x_init[3] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    gsl_vector_view x = gsl_vector_view_array (x_init, p);
    const gsl_rng_type * type;
    gsl_rng * r;

    gsl_rng_env_setup();

    type = gsl_rng_default;
    r = gsl_rng_alloc (type);

    f.f = &expb_f;
    f.df = &expb_df;
    f.fdf = &expb_fdf;
    f.n = n;
    f.p = p;
    f.params = &d;

  /* This is the data to be fitted */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double t = i;
        y[i] = 1.0 + 5 * exp (-0.1 * t) + gsl_ran_gaussian (r, 0.1);
        sigma[i] = 0.1;
        printf ("data: %u %g %g\n", i, y[i], sigma[i]);
    };
    T = gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_lmsder;
    s = gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_alloc (T, n, p);
    gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_set (s, &f, &x.vector);

    print_state (iter, s);

    do
    {
        iter++;
        status = gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_iterate (s);

        printf ("status = %s\n", gsl_strerror (status));

        print_state (iter, s);

        if (status)
        break;

        status = gsl_multifit_test_delta (s->dx, s->x,
                                        1e-4, 1e-4);
    }
    while (status == GSL_CONTINUE && iter < 500);
    gsl_multifit_covar (s->J, 0.0, covar);
    {
        double chi = gsl_blas_dnrm2(s->f);
        double dof = n - p;
        double c = GSL_MAX_DBL(1, chi / sqrt(dof));

        printf("chisq/dof = %g\n",  pow(chi, 2.0) / dof);

        printf ("A      = %.5f +/- %.5f\n", FIT(0), c*ERR(0));
        printf ("lambda = %.5f +/- %.5f\n", FIT(1), c*ERR(1));
        printf ("b      = %.5f +/- %.5f\n", FIT(2), c*ERR(2));
    }

    printf ("status = %s\n", gsl_strerror (status));

    gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_free (s);
    gsl_matrix_free (covar);
    gsl_rng_free (r);
    return 0;
}

void print_state (size_t iter, gsl_multifit_fdfsolver * s)
{
    printf ("iter: %3u x = % 15.8f % 15.8f % 15.8f "
          "|f(x)| = %g\n",
          iter,
          gsl_vector_get (s->x, 0),
          gsl_vector_get (s->x, 1),
          gsl_vector_get (s->x, 2),
          gsl_blas_dnrm2 (s->f));
}
```

Ideally it should simply generate a short data set that follows a decaying exponential with some white noise on top and then fit it.

To get it running in Code::Blocks in windows I followed the procedure outlined here: [installing GSL on Windows XP 32bit for use with codeblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202598/installing-gsl-on-windows-xp-32bit-for-use-with-codeblocks)

It compiles without warnings even with -Wall and -Wextra flags. However, it fails on the line: `gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_set (s, &f, &x.vector);` with the error: `multifit\fdfsolver.c:132: ERROR: vector length does not match solver. Default GSL error handler invoked.`

I was a little surprised to find this in what should be raw example code, but here we are. So I am hoping someone more knowledgeable than I can tell me what I am doing wrong with this simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: They were allocating their initial vector wrong. The fixed code is here:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_multifit_nlin.h>
#define N 40
#define FIT(i) gsl_vector_get(s->x, i)
#define ERR(i) sqrt(gsl_matrix_get(covar,i,i))

struct data {
    size_t n;
    double * y;
    double * sigma;
};

int expb_f (const gsl_vector * x, void *data, gsl_vector * f)
{
    size_t n = ((struct data *)data)->n;
    double *y = ((struct data *)data)->y;
    double *sigma = ((struct data *) data)->sigma;

    double A = gsl_vector_get (x, 0);
    double lambda = gsl_vector_get (x, 1);
    double b = gsl_vector_get (x, 2);

    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        /* Model Yi = A * exp(-lambda * i) + b */
        double t = i;
        double Yi = A * exp (-lambda * t) + b;
        gsl_vector_set (f, i, (Yi - y[i])/sigma[i]);
    }

    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

int expb_df (const gsl_vector * x, void *data, gsl_matrix * J)
{
    size_t n = ((struct data *)data)->n;
    double *sigma = ((struct data *) data)->sigma;

    double A = gsl_vector_get (x, 0);
    double lambda = gsl_vector_get (x, 1);

    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        /* Jacobian matrix J(i,j) = dfi / dxj, */
        /* where fi = (Yi - yi)/sigma[i],      */
        /*       Yi = A * exp(-lambda * i) + b  */
        /* and the xj are the parameters (A,lambda,b) */
        double t = i;
        double s = sigma[i];
        double e = exp(-lambda * t);
        gsl_matrix_set (J, i, 0, e/s);
        gsl_matrix_set (J, i, 1, -t * A * e/s);
        gsl_matrix_set (J, i, 2, 1/s);
    }
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

int expb_fdf (const gsl_vector * x, void *data, gsl_vector * f, gsl_matrix * J)
{
    expb_f (x, data, f);
    expb_df (x, data, J);

    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}


void print_state (size_t iter, gsl_multifit_fdfsolver * s);

int main (void)
{
    const gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_type *T;
    gsl_multifit_fdfsolver *s;
    int status;
    unsigned int i, iter = 0;
    const size_t n = N;
    const size_t p = 3;

    gsl_matrix *covar = gsl_matrix_alloc (p, p);
    double y[N], sigma[N];
    struct data d = { n, y, sigma};
    gsl_multifit_function_fdf f;
    gsl_vector *x = gsl_vector_alloc(p);
    for (i=0; i<p; i++)
    {
        gsl_vector_set(x,i,i==0 ? 1 : 0);
    }
    const gsl_rng_type * type;
    gsl_rng * r;

    gsl_rng_env_setup();

    type = gsl_rng_default;
    r = gsl_rng_alloc (type);

    f.f = &expb_f;
    f.df = &expb_df;
    f.fdf = &expb_fdf;
    f.n = n;
    f.p = p;
    f.params = &d;

  /* This is the data to be fitted */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double t = i;
        y[i] = 1.0 + 5 * exp (-0.1 * t) + gsl_ran_gaussian (r, 0.1);
        sigma[i] = 0.1;
        printf ("data: %u %g %g\n", i, y[i], sigma[i]);
    };
    T = gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_lmsder;
    s = gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_alloc (T, n, p);
    gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_set (s, &f, x);

    print_state (iter, s);

    do
    {
        iter++;
        status = gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_iterate (s);

        printf ("status = %s\n", gsl_strerror (status));

        print_state (iter, s);

        if (status)
        break;

        status = gsl_multifit_test_delta (s->dx, s->x,
                                        1e-4, 1e-4);
    }
    while (status == GSL_CONTINUE && iter < 500);
    gsl_multifit_covar (s->J, 0.0, covar);
    {
        double chi = gsl_blas_dnrm2(s->f);
        double dof = n - p;
        double c = GSL_MAX_DBL(1, chi / sqrt(dof));

        printf("chisq/dof = %g\n",  pow(chi, 2.0) / dof);

        printf ("A      = %.5f +/- %.5f\n", FIT(0), c*ERR(0));
        printf ("lambda = %.5f +/- %.5f\n", FIT(1), c*ERR(1));
        printf ("b      = %.5f +/- %.5f\n", FIT(2), c*ERR(2));
    }

    printf ("status = %s\n", gsl_strerror (status));

    gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_free (s);
    gsl_matrix_free (covar);
    gsl_rng_free (r);
    gsl_vector_free(x);
    return 0;
}

void print_state (size_t iter, gsl_multifit_fdfsolver * s)
{
    printf ("iter: %3u x = % 15.8f % 15.8f % 15.8f "
          "|f(x)| = %g\n",
          iter,
          gsl_vector_get (s->x, 0),
          gsl_vector_get (s->x, 1),
          gsl_vector_get (s->x, 2),
          gsl_blas_dnrm2 (s->f));
}
```